# Synchronous request using Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have checked other solutions like [How to make a synchronous request using Alamofire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961010/how-to-make-a-synchronous-request-using-alamofire), I followed all instructions but I haven't been able to complete the requests and then use the information.

I need to retrieve distance and route points from google maps and then complete an array with that information.
This is the function:

```
func getGoogleMapsInfo(startLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D, restaurant: Customer, completion: @escaping (_ distance: Int, _ routePoints: String)  -> ()){

    let endLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: restaurant.latitude, longitude: restaurant.longitude)
    let origin = "\(startLocation.latitude),\(startLocation.longitude)"
    let destination = "\(endLocation.latitude),\(endLocation.longitude)"
    var distance = 0
    var routePoints = ""

    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&mode=walking"
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .success:

            do {
                self.json = try JSON(data: response.data!)

                distance = Int(truncating: self.json["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["distance"]["value"].numberValue)


                let route = self.json["routes"].arrayValue.first
                let routeOverviewPolyline = route!["overview_polyline"].dictionary
                routePoints = (routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue)!
                completion(distance, routePoints)
                break
            } catch {
                print("error JSON")
            }


        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completion(distance, routePoints)
            break
        }

    }


}
```

And this is how I call it:

```
    for index in 0...nearbyRestaurants.count - 1 {

        getGoogleMapsInfo(startLocation: currentLocation, restaurant: nearbyRestaurants[index]) { (distance, routePoints) in
            nearbyRestaurants[index].distance = distance
            nearbyRestaurants[index].routePoints = routePoints
        }

    }
```

I'd really appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: "checked other solutions like How to make a synchronous request using Alamofire?" Don't check them. Never never never network synchronously. Never. Did I mention never?

Comment: @matt synchronous network requests are OK from a background thread.

Comment: @Cristik Did I mention "except when you're already on a background thread"?

Comment: @matt I might've seen that somewhere :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to make an asynchronous request synchronous

Instead use `DispatchGroup`,`notify` is called when all network requests are completed.

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
for index in 0..<nearbyRestaurants.count {
    group.enter()
    getGoogleMapsInfo(startLocation: currentLocation, restaurant: nearbyRestaurants[index]) { (distance, routePoints) in
        nearbyRestaurants[index].distance = distance
        nearbyRestaurants[index].routePoints = routePoints
        group.leave()
    }
}
group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        print("all info data has been received")
}
```